# How to find out if a string contains digits followed by alphabet characters?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I find out whether a given string contains at least one number followed by alphabets using Regex in c#?

For example :

```
var strInput="Test123Test";
```

The function should return a bool value.

Comment: If string contains numbers followed by alphabet,i want some bool value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"\d\p{L}");
```

will return `True` for your sample string. Currently, this regex also considers non-ASCII digits and letters as valid matches, if you don't want that, use `@"[0-9][A-Za-z])"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match 123 only then:-

```
Match m = Regex.Match("Test123Test", @"(\p{L}+)(\d+)") ; 
string result = m.Groups[2].Value
```

If you want to get the bool value then do this:-

```
 Console.WriteLine(!String.IsNullOrEmtpty(result))) ;
```

or simple use:-

```
  Regex.IsMatch("Test123Test", @"\p{L}+\d+") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(strInput, @"[0-9][A-Za-z]"))
...
```